# Editing XML attribute in Powershell on seemingly non-null object - "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to set the scan-interval attribute of the deployment-scanner subsystem in my Wildfly standalone.xml using Powershell. Whenever I try to execute any method against the element (System.Xml.XmlElement), I get "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.", but the object on which I am calling the method does not appear to be null.

```
> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17134  407

> $Standalone="C:\Users\I10674\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml"
> $Standalone | Get-Member

    TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition
----             ----------            ----------
Clone            Method                System.Object Clone(), System.Object ICloneable.Clone()
CompareTo        Method                int CompareTo(System.Object value), int CompareTo(string strB), int IComparab...
Contains         Method                bool Contains(string value)
CopyTo           Method                void CopyTo(int sourceIndex, char[] destination, int destinationIndex, int co...
EndsWith         Method                bool EndsWith(string value), bool EndsWith(string value, System.StringCompari...
Equals           Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool Equals(string value), bool Equals(string...
GetEnumerator    Method                System.CharEnumerator GetEnumerator(), System.Collections.IEnumerator IEnumer...
GetHashCode      Method                int GetHashCode()
GetType          Method                type GetType()
GetTypeCode      Method                System.TypeCode GetTypeCode(), System.TypeCode IConvertible.GetTypeCode()
IndexOf          Method                int IndexOf(char value), int IndexOf(char value, int startIndex), int IndexOf...
IndexOfAny       Method                int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex), i...
Insert           Method                string Insert(int startIndex, string value)
IsNormalized     Method                bool IsNormalized(), bool IsNormalized(System.Text.NormalizationForm normaliz...
LastIndexOf      Method                int LastIndexOf(char value), int LastIndexOf(char value, int startIndex), int...
LastIndexOfAny   Method                int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startI...
Normalize        Method                string Normalize(), string Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm normalizat...
PadLeft          Method                string PadLeft(int totalWidth), string PadLeft(int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
PadRight         Method                string PadRight(int totalWidth), string PadRight(int totalWidth, char padding...
Remove           Method                string Remove(int startIndex, int count), string Remove(int startIndex)
Replace          Method                string Replace(char oldChar, char newChar), string Replace(string oldValue, s...
Split            Method                string[] Split(Params char[] separator), string[] Split(char[] separator, int...
StartsWith       Method                bool StartsWith(string value), bool StartsWith(string value, System.StringCom...
Substring        Method                string Substring(int startIndex), string Substring(int startIndex, int length)
ToBoolean        Method                bool IConvertible.ToBoolean(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToByte           Method                byte IConvertible.ToByte(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToChar           Method                char IConvertible.ToChar(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToCharArray      Method                char[] ToCharArray(), char[] ToCharArray(int startIndex, int length)
ToDateTime       Method                datetime IConvertible.ToDateTime(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToDecimal        Method                decimal IConvertible.ToDecimal(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToDouble         Method                double IConvertible.ToDouble(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToInt16          Method                int16 IConvertible.ToInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToInt32          Method                int IConvertible.ToInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToInt64          Method                long IConvertible.ToInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToLower          Method                string ToLower(), string ToLower(cultureinfo culture)
ToLowerInvariant Method                string ToLowerInvariant()
ToSByte          Method                sbyte IConvertible.ToSByte(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToSingle         Method                float IConvertible.ToSingle(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToString         Method                string ToString(), string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider), string I...
ToType           Method                System.Object IConvertible.ToType(type conversionType, System.IFormatProvider...
ToUInt16         Method                uint16 IConvertible.ToUInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToUInt32         Method                uint32 IConvertible.ToUInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToUInt64         Method                uint64 IConvertible.ToUInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToUpper          Method                string ToUpper(), string ToUpper(cultureinfo culture)
ToUpperInvariant Method                string ToUpperInvariant()
Trim             Method                string Trim(Params char[] trimChars), string Trim()
TrimEnd          Method                string TrimEnd(Params char[] trimChars)
TrimStart        Method                string TrimStart(Params char[] trimChars)
Chars            ParameterizedProperty char Chars(int index) {get;}
Length           Property              int Length {get;}

> [xml]$XmlContent=$(Get-Content "$Standalone")
> $XmlContent

xml           server
---           ------
version="1.0" server

> $DeploymentScanner=$XmlContent.server.profile.subsystem.'deployment-scanner'
> $DeploymentScanner

name                            : default
path                            : deployments
scan-enabled                    : true
scan-interval                   : 0
relative-to                     : jboss.server.base.dir
runtime-failure-causes-rollback : ${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}

> $DeploymentScanner | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.Xml.XmlElement#urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0#deployment-scanner

Name                            MemberType            Definition
----                            ----------            ----------
ToString                        CodeMethod            static string XmlNode(psobject instance)
AppendChild                     Method                System.Xml.XmlNode AppendChild(System.Xml.XmlNode newChild)
Clone                           Method                System.Xml.XmlNode Clone(), System.Object ICloneable.Clone()
CloneNode                       Method                System.Xml.XmlNode CloneNode(bool deep)
CreateNavigator                 Method                System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator CreateNavigator(), System.Xml....
Equals                          Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetAttribute                    Method                string GetAttribute(string name), string GetAttribute(string l...
GetAttributeNode                Method                System.Xml.XmlAttribute GetAttributeNode(string name), System....
GetElementsByTagName            Method                System.Xml.XmlNodeList GetElementsByTagName(string name), Syst...
GetEnumerator                   Method                System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator(), System.Collect...
GetHashCode                     Method                int GetHashCode()
GetNamespaceOfPrefix            Method                string GetNamespaceOfPrefix(string prefix)
GetPrefixOfNamespace            Method                string GetPrefixOfNamespace(string namespaceURI)
GetType                         Method                type GetType()
HasAttribute                    Method                bool HasAttribute(string name), bool HasAttribute(string local...
InsertAfter                     Method                System.Xml.XmlNode InsertAfter(System.Xml.XmlNode newChild, Sy...
InsertBefore                    Method                System.Xml.XmlNode InsertBefore(System.Xml.XmlNode newChild, S...
Normalize                       Method                void Normalize()
PrependChild                    Method                System.Xml.XmlNode PrependChild(System.Xml.XmlNode newChild)
RemoveAll                       Method                void RemoveAll()
RemoveAllAttributes             Method                void RemoveAllAttributes()
RemoveAttribute                 Method                void RemoveAttribute(string name), void RemoveAttribute(string...
RemoveAttributeAt               Method                System.Xml.XmlNode RemoveAttributeAt(int i)
RemoveAttributeNode             Method                System.Xml.XmlAttribute RemoveAttributeNode(System.Xml.XmlAttr...
RemoveChild                     Method                System.Xml.XmlNode RemoveChild(System.Xml.XmlNode oldChild)
ReplaceChild                    Method                System.Xml.XmlNode ReplaceChild(System.Xml.XmlNode newChild, S...
SelectNodes                     Method                System.Xml.XmlNodeList SelectNodes(string xpath), System.Xml.X...
SelectSingleNode                Method                System.Xml.XmlNode SelectSingleNode(string xpath), System.Xml....
SetAttribute                    Method                void SetAttribute(string name, string value), string SetAttrib...
SetAttributeNode                Method                System.Xml.XmlAttribute SetAttributeNode(System.Xml.XmlAttribu...
Supports                        Method                bool Supports(string feature, string version)
WriteContentTo                  Method                void WriteContentTo(System.Xml.XmlWriter w)
WriteTo                         Method                void WriteTo(System.Xml.XmlWriter w)
Item                            ParameterizedProperty System.Xml.XmlElement Item(string name) {get;}, System.Xml.Xml...
name                            Property              string name {get;set;}
path                            Property              string path {get;set;}
relative-to                     Property              string relative-to {get;set;}
runtime-failure-causes-rollback Property              string runtime-failure-causes-rollback {get;set;}
scan-enabled                    Property              string scan-enabled {get;set;}
scan-interval                   Property              string scan-interval {get;set;}

> # Can access properties just fine
> $DeploymentScanner.'scan-interval'
0

> $DeploymentScanner.path
deployments

> # Method fails
> $DeploymentScanner.SetAttribute("scan-interval", "1000")

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $DeploymentScanner.SetAttribute("scan-interval", "1000")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

> if ($DeploymentScanner) { Write-Host "not null" } else { Write-Host "is null" }
not null
```

I'm really confused as to how when I log $DeploymentScanner and pipe it to Get-Member, it can identify the class and display all of the available methods. It even shows that scan-interval is one of the properties. According to my if check at the end, it is not null -- why I am getting this error?

Comment: I might be wrong but I think you don't need to set an attibute you should change the value of the node `scan-interval`. Isn't it?

Comment: You've run into a gotcha that comes with dot-accesing XML data structures. Either do as Olaf suggested, or use `SelectNodes()` instead of dot-access, in which case you probably need a namespace manager too.